# A sintaxe '///' tem algum significado especial?

Tags: javascript, sintaxe, notepad++

Estava a usar o notepad++ (v 6.5) para escrever um arquivo em javascript quando notei o seguinte:

[image]

Escrevi uma linha de comentário iniciando com `///`, três em vez do usual duas. Na execução essa linha parece ser ignorada, mas ela não é colorida como um comentário. (Note também que o fundo da linha está branco, de cor diferente). Isso é um bug no syntax highlighter do notepad++ ou é alguma sintaxe especial do javascript que desconheço? Algo relacionado a `/regex/`?

Comment: A meu ver é um bug do notepad++. eu uso o eclipse e é referenciado como comentário da mesma forma, com 3 ou mais *slash's*

Comment: Aqui tenho a versão 5.6 e fica como comentário. Provavelmente um bug introduzido no parser.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Esse conjunto de três barras é comumente utilizado por alguns programas para formatação de documentação de código (como o [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html)), como forma de indicar que o comentário de uma única linha deve ser incluido na documentação gerada. Na prática não deixa de ser um comentário de uma linha, mas é um comentário especial.

Alguns editores, como o [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb514138%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), por exemplo, colorizam esses comentários de forma diferenciada justamente pra indicar que se trata de uma documentação. Outros, não diferenciam isso de um comentário normal (como no caso do próprio StackOverflow - vide abaixo). A função abaixo (extraída do link referido acima para o Visual Studio) exemplifica o uso desse tipo de comentário:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function areaFunction(radiusParam)
{
    /// <summary>Determines the area of a circle based on a radius parameter.</summary>
    /// <param name="radius" type="Number">The radius of the circle.</param>
    /// <returns type="Number">The area.</returns>
    var areaVal;
    areaVal = Math.PI * radiusParam * radiusParam;
    return areaVal;
    // Note como o StackOverflow NÃO COLORE esse comentário DE FORMA DIFERENTE do anterior...
}
</script>
```

O colorizador (*syntax highlighter*) do Notepad++ (a versão de referência é a 6.5.5) é capaz de diferenciar esses caracteres de um comentário simples. Em algumas linguagens em que esse uso é mais comum, há uma configuração específica para isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu intencionalmente mudei o estilo de comentários de documentação (COMMENT LINE DOC) em Java* para azul, como forma de ilustrar. Isso é feito diretamente na ferramenta "Configurador de Estilos" disponível no menu "Configurações" do Notepad++:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>* **Apesar do Notepad++ colorir comentários com três barras de forma diferenciada (para indicar documentação), não há referências a esse estilo além do `/** <codigo> */` na documentação do Javadoc - conforme indicado em comentário efetuado nesta resposta.**</sup>

No caso do Javascript, o Notepad++ também diferencia esse comentário do "comum", *mas não fornece uma opção de colorização exclusiva para ele* (como faz no caso do Java). Honestamente, eu não entendo o motivo da falta dessa opção pra configuração de cor, uma vez que a distinção é claramente efetuada (se existe um bug ele talvez esteja nessa falta de configuração, não na diferenciação dos tipos de comentários).

Só pra ser preciso a respeito do que ocorre no caso desse comentário com três barras *no caso do Javascript*, a linha recai na configuração padrão (*default*) dos estilos globais (*global styles*), e por isso tem a cor de fundo em branco distinta do restante do arquivo. Se for do seu interesse, você pode ainda assim definir a cor para o Javascript mudando aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Hum... legal saber de tudo isso. **MAS, no Java, não é nada comum usar três barras.** Não encontrei nenhuma referência sobre isso no Javadoc. Vi que esse recurso é usado em C# ou C++ no Visual Studio, mas seria apenas algo visual, pois documentação em comentários simples também são lidas.

Comment: @utluiz Vc tem razão, desculpe. Eu jurava que o Javadoc também utilizava essa formatação, mas também fui procurar e não achei na documentação. Achei [essa requisição](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4910797) bem antiga, mas que aparentemente não foi pra frente. Vou tirar a referência ao Javadoc da resposta. Valeu pelo aviso!

Answer (score 4):

Segundo a [Especificação ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4), no caso de comentários de *linha única*, é aceito qualquer tipo de caractere após a adição das duas "barras" que iniciam o comentário (`//`).

Sendo assim, apesar da mudança de cor no seu editor, o comentário em JavaScript ainda é válido.

Comment: Não me parece um bug do Notepad++, apenas uma cor diferente para indicar uma [marcação de documentação do código](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17332025/2896619).

Comment: @LuizVieira boa colocação, não tinha pensado neste motivo. Fiz uma alteração na última linha removendo o termo "bug".