# Comportamento estranho em uma possível forma de fazer comentário

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho duas funções

```
/########### CARREGAR - LANÇAMENTO ###########/
var carregar_parametros=function(){
    alert('asd');
}
/########### CADASTRAR - LANÇAMENTO ###########/
var cadastrar_parametro=function(){
    if($("#lancamento").val()!=''){
        UiLoading.show();
        $.post('/paginas/teste/cadastrar_parametro',{
            lancamento:$("#lancamento").val(),
            tipo:$("#tipo").val(),
            ativo:$("#lancamento_ativo").attr('checked')=='checked' ? '1' : '0'
            },function(){
                carregar_parametros();
                UiLoading.hide();
                $("#cancelar_parametro").click()
                UiAlert('Parâmetro cadastrado com sucesso!','Atenção');
        });
    }else{
        UiAlert('Por favor, preencha os campos nulos!','Atenção');
    }
}
```

quando eu faço a função `cadastrar_parametro` com o comentário 
 `/########### CADASTRAR - LANÇAMENTO ###########/` não dá erro nenhum mas quando eu faço a função `carregar_parametros` com o mesmo estilo de comentário ele dá erro

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

E quando testo na extensão **firebug** do Firefox ele me mostra isso

> SyntaxError: illegal character     /########### CADASTRAR - LANÇAMENTO
>
> #####/

O que pode ser?

Comment: Os comentários em JS não deveriam ser // para uma linha, /**/ para multi-linha?

Comment: @Omni sim, mas há um tempo atrás fiz teste com este tipo de comentário e deu certo

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, se funcionou a algum tempo, eu não sei, mais essa não é uma forma padrão de comentário em javascript. E não vejo problema nenhum em utilizar o comentário comum do javascript: `/*########### CARREGAR - LANÇAMENTO ###########*/`, não vejo razão para quer inventar =/.

Comment: talvez as `/## algo ##/` seja interpretado como uma regex

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha ao olhar para o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qN6e/) dá para reparar que o primeiro / (antes de carregar_parametros) está a ser considerado como um caracter. O que não acontece no /## seguinte (antes de cadastrar_parametro).
De qualquer forma acho que seria uma boa prática usar a forma de comentários do JS.

Comment: @Fernando Não é irrelevante! Este tipo de dúvida é comum a qualquer um quando se está aprendendo uma nova linguagem de programação.

Comment: @Fernando conhecimento da linguagem nunca é irrelevante e aposto que você não sabia que era possível fazer comentários dessa forma

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha a questão é que não existe documentação que prove que os comentários possam ser feitos dessa forma (pelo menos não encontro). E tal como a pergunta dá a entender, fazer desta forma provoca comportamento estranho.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, essa não é uma forma de comentário do javascript, como demostrado [neste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Code_comments) link, que o Andrey citou. E essa pergunta me parece um tanto quanto forçada, pois esse tipo de comentário não é necessário, e acredito que você já sabia disso antes mesmo de perguntar aqui.

Comment: @Fernando não é necessário mais é possível, talvez isso possa ser até um erro do javascript e esse é o primeiro poste que fala sobre esse comportamento estranho, e não é descontextualizada porque a pergunta está bem clara.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha a forma como vc escreve o comentário é interpretado na linguagem JavaScript como uma expressão regular como na resposta do GuilhermeBernal, esse não é um padrão de comentário sua pergunta é realmente descontextualizada pois o titulo é "Tipos de comentário" e o que vc propôs aqui como tipo de comentário não existe e qualquer um que estiver "aprendendo" javascript saberá disso quando ele encontrar esse post ele apenas se confundirá com seu tipo "Regex/Comentario", isso não é um erro! é a mesma coisa de vc perguntar pq um exe não abre no Lion ou seja não é assim que funciona

Comment: @TuyoshiVinicius e descontextualizado diz : `Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.`              --   Realmente ela não é de programação ??????

Comment: @Tuyoshi O que é obvio para você não é obvio para outra pessoa. Se você vê um código que usa essa sintaxe para escrever um comentário (que diga-se de passagem funciona e é perfeitamente válida, desde que os pontos e vírgulas estejam no lugar), é justo perguntar como isso aconteceu. Especialmente se a pessoa não conhece expressões regulares. Essa é uma sintaxe que ela nunca viu antes e que se comporta como um comentário. Seguindo sua lógica, essa pergunta também deve ser fechada, certo? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14788/a-sintaxe-tem-algum-significado-especial

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Respondendo mais diretamente:

Um comentário em JavaScript é escrito da seguinte forma:

```
// Isso é um comentário.
/* Ou isso também é */
```

Poderá achar mais detalhes em qualquer livro ou referência que queira.

Sobre especificamente o seu código, você tem isso aqui:

```
/########### CARREGAR - LANÇAMENTO ###########/
```

Essa é a sintaxe para declarar um expressão regular. `/isso é uma regex/`. Isso é um objeto que pode ser posto em uma variável, da mesma forma que um número ou uma string. Isso não faz nada da mesma forma que esse código não faz nada:

```
4
```

O problema do erro está nos pontos e vírgulas. Observe:

```
var carregar_parametros = function() {/* ... */}
```

O que está fazendo é o mesmo que por um valor (a função) em uma variável. Semanticamente é o mesmo que:

```
var a = 5
```

Mas você não colocou ponto e vírgula no final! Isso é um erro de sintaxe:

```
var a = 5
/regex/
```

Pois é lido assim:

```
var a = 5/regex/
```

Adicionar um ponto e vírgula no fim da declaração da função resolve. Mas sinceramente... use comentários de verdade!

Comment: Enfim uma resposta explicativa do problema, ao contrário das outras que só me deram sugestões.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas acrescentando aos comentários que já responderam os formatos de comentários do JavaScript, procure sobre padronização de escrita de código (coding standards), o que facilita a manutenção do código por você ou qualquer outra pessoa.

Veja que:

```
//###### CADASTRAR LANÇAMENTO ####### //
var funcao = function () {};
```

Pode parecer um bom destaque no código para separar as diferentes funções, mas um comentário no estilo "JAVADOC" pode ser muito mais útil e elegante, principalmente por ser amplamente utilizado:

```
/**
 * Carrega a UI e efetua o cadastro de um lancamento.
 * @return void
 */
var funcao = function () {};
```

Answer (score 1):

No Javascript use `//` para comentários de uma linha e `/* (...) */` para comentários de 2 ou mais linhas.

*[Veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Code_comments)*.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode estar utilizando `/ /` para uma unica linha e `/* */` para múltiplas linhas para comentários em *JavaScript*.

```
// Comentário de uma linha

/*
   Comentário com
   Múltiplas
   Linhas
*/
```

<sub>[`Comment Statements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/6s6fab9k%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)</sub>

Mesmo [não sendo necessário o ponto e vírgula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1834674/1608936) no final de uma função, acredito que se você o usa-se evitaria o erro já explicado na resposta do @Guilherme Bernal.

```
/########### CARREGAR - LANÇAMENTO ###########/
var carregar_parametros=function() {}; // <--
/########### CADASTRAR - LANÇAMENTO ###########/
var cadastrar_parametro=function() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar os comentários:

`/* */` ou `//`

E não é bom usar `/ #### ... ### /` porque isso é uma regex. Espero ter ajudado.